# nHibernate - Query over many-to-many

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have trouble querying an object with a many-to-many-relationship.

My model looks like this. Therefore the m-n-relation is resolved against itself.

```
ProductionOrder           Product              ProductPart
   +-----+                +-----+                +-----+
   |     |                |     | 1------------n |     |    
   |     |  n --------- 1 |     |                |     |
   |     |                |     | n------------1 |     |
   +-----+                +-----+                +-----+
```

One product can be part of many products and one product can have many parts.
I now try to retrieve the `ProductionOrder` where given product is part of the 
product to be produced.

In plain SQL this is pretty simple and works perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM ProductionOrder po
INNER JOIN Product p 
ON po.ProductId = p.Id
INNER JOIN ProductPart pp
ON p.Id = pp.ContainingProductId
WHERE pp.PartProductId = 403
```

---

But I fail to make this in nHibernate.

**First Try:**
I tried following Query which returns nothing:

```
private decimal GetNeededForProduction(Product product)
{
    //Retrieve all ProductionOrders where Product is a Part
    var productionOrders = Session.Query<ProductionOrder>()
        .Where(x => x.Product.Parts.Select(p => p.PartProduct.Id).Contains(product.Id))
        .Fetch(x => x.Product).ThenFetch(x => x.Parts)
        .ToList();
}
```

**Second Try:**
I also found that WhereRestriction has a method `IsIn` but thats just the other way around.

```
var test = Session.QueryOver<ProductionOrder>()
                .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Product.Parts.Select(p => p.PartProduct.Id)).IsIn(new long[] {product.Id});
```

And also throws an exception

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
variable 'x' of type 'Pmc.Model.Production.ProductionOrder' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

**Third Try:**

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<ProductionOrder>()
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver<ProductPart>(x => x.Product.Parts)
            .Where(pp => pp.PartProduct.Id == product.Id).List<ProductionOrder>();
```

This throws

```
{"The multi-part identifier \"productpar1_.PartProductId\" could not be bound."}
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit1 - Added the c#-model-classes and mappings**

```
public class Product 
{
    //More properties
    public virtual IList<ProductPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPart : IHaveId
{
    /// <summary> parent </summary>
    public virtual Product ContainingProduct { get; set; }
    /// <summary> child </summary>
    public virtual Product PartProduct { get; set; }

    //More properties      
}
```

**Mappings**

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Parts).KeyColumn("ContainingProductId").Inverse().Cascade.DeleteOrphan().BatchSize(20);
    }
}

public class ProductPartMap : ClassMap<ProductPart>
{
    public ProductPartMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.ContainingProduct);
        References(x => x.PartProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us the C# entities... It isn't exactly clear how the Product<->ProductPart relationship is built.

Comment: @xanatos added model and mapping, I hope now the relationships are clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<ProductionOrder>()
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Product>(x => x.Product)
    .Inner.JoinQueryOver<ProductPart>(x => x.Parts)
    .Where(x => x.PartProduct.Id == product.Id)
    .List();
```

Note that in NHibernate the "natural join conditions" (primary key/foreign key) are implicitly given by the `JoinQueryOver`, so you don't have to repeat them.

Comment: In my case it must be `Where(x => x.PartProduct.Id == product.Id)`. The rest works perfectly. Thank you so much!